# Is there a tidy way to define a large watch collection for AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am using this code:

```
        $scope.$watchCollection('[config.examId, config.pageType, config.createdBy, config.modifiedBy, config.reference]',
            function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (typeof newValue !== 'undefined' && typeof oldValue !== 'undefined' && newValue !== oldValue) {
                    _u.putConfigs($scope.config);
                    //$scope.grid.data = null;
                };
             });
```

Now I have to add more items to the collection. Is there a way that I can neatly spread these over multiple lines? From what I understand (might be wrong). The watchCollection has to be a string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, as looks like you use simple fields inside of your configuration object you can easily modify this to have multiple watch (which can be more flexible in this way). Even if you have complex objects you can watch them by using deep flag:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ConfigCtrl', function($scope, $parse, $log) {
    $scope.config = {};

    // initial configuration
    $scope.watchProperties = ['examId', 'pageType', 'createdBy', 
                          'modifiedBy'];

    // dynamic modifications to the watched properties
    $scope.configureWatchProperties = function() {
        $scope.watchProperties.push('reference');
    }

    $scope.updateConfig = function() {
        // TODO: update config here
        $log.log('config updated:', $scope.config);
    }

    $scope.addWatchProperty = function(context, property, deep) {
        $scope.$watch(function() {
            return $parse(property)(context);
        }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue && newValue !== oldValue) {
                $scope.updateConfig();
            }
        }, deep);
    }

    $scope.configureWatch = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.watchProperties, function(prop) {
            $scope.addWatchProperty($scope.config, prop);
        });
    }

    $scope.configureWatchProperties();
    $scope.configureWatch();
});
```

[Complete JSFiddle Example:](http://jsfiddle.net/kailex/3hMK8/5/)

Comment: What is the advantage over using the builtin $watchCollection? Also the line `return $parse(property)(context);` will most likely have a performance impact, since this will be executed multiple times on _every_ $digest.

Comment: No, $parse has no impact as it is very simple for this case. It was added for flexibility because you can use more complex expressions there. I think, $watchCollection does the similar thing and in this case it is more flexible and transparent.

Answer (score 1):

If you can just watch the whole collection as null suggested, that'd be the way to go. If you can't for whatever reason, you could also watch individual values like this:

```
var toWatch = [
    'config.examId',
    'config.pageType',
    'config.createdBy',
    'config.modifiedBy',
    'config.reference'
];
toWatch.forEach(function (watchExpression) {
    $scope.$watch(watchExpression,
        function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (typeof newValue !== 'undefined' && typeof oldValue !== 'undefined' && newValue !== oldValue) {
                _u.putConfigs($scope.config);
                //$scope.grid.data = null;
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument passed to `watchCollection` can be an expression (string) or a function, which should return the watched object. By passing `'[config.examId, config.pageType, /* ... */ ]'` to `$watchCollection` will cause angular to create a **new** array on every *digest* cycle. It works, but it's probably not what you want.

#### Expression

```
$scope.myArray = [ $scope.config.examId, $scope.config.pageType, /* ... */ ];
$scope.$watchCollection('myArray', function(newValue, oldValue) { 
  /* do magic */ 
});
```

#### Function

```
var myArray = [ $scope.config.examId, $scope.config.pageType, /* ... */ ];
$scope.$watchCollection(function() {
  // Edit: oops typo ... return array should have been;
  return myArray;
}, function(newValue, oldValue) { 
  /* do magic */ 
});
```

#### Object

Note that you can also watch an object instead of an array:

```
$scope.config = { /* your properties */ };

$scope.$watchCollection('config', function() { 
  /* do magic */ 
});

$scope.myProperty = 'this will fire the callback';
```

Comment: Where's myArray used in the Function? Also are you suggesting  to use the code under the Expression title? I am a bit confused what you are doing with the code under the Function title.

Comment: Yeah, sorry ... made a typo. Corrected it. And you can use either way; expression or function. In both situations Angular will use the result of the function or the result of the expression. Using _expressions_ allows you to point to values on the scope. Using a _function_ allows to use values _not_ on the scope.

Comment: $scope.myArray = [config.examId, config.pageType, /* ... */]; does not work :-(  It gives an error saying there is no such object as config.examId

Comment: Just add $scope in front of it: `$scope.myArray = [ $scope.config.examId ]`