# AngularJS: Way to define a large $watchCollection?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

This post is not the same as: [Is there a tidy way to define a large watch collection for AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22525747/is-there-a-tidy-way-to-define-a-large-watch-collection-for-angularjs)

My code is (service.js):

```
var MyJSON = {
    array: [
        {k:'v'},
        {k:'v'},
        {k:'v'}
    ],
    info: {
        k: 'v',
        k2: 'v2'
    },
    last: 1398680914943 // Date.now()
}

$rootScope.$watchCollection(function () { return MyJSON; }, function (n, o) {
    console.log('Change');
});
```

Detects changes when I work on the root object "MyJSON". Like this:

```
MyJSON.last = 123456789; // console: Change
```

But if I am doing something like this:

```
MyJSON.info.k = 'vDummie';
```

or:

```
MyJSON.array.push({k:'something'});
```

"$watchCollection" does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$watchCollection` watches only the 1st level properties; use `$watch(..., ..., true)` to do "deep" watching. Note: there are 3 arguments, the first two are the same as your code, the third is `true` for deep watch.